# Full Name Validation for first name, middle name, and last name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Phone which is can separate the Full Name of person

exp:
in the name fields i write
Dave Edward James David

and 
when i open contact person information that phone already separating the full name into first middle and last name

like 
****first name : Dave

middle name (first): Edward

middle name (second) : James

last name : David*
***

there is the problem, how to do that on PHP validation? is it using implode / explode function? if it's yes, please give some example.
sorry for my english

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The way it works here: You have a problem, then you try to fix it, and if you fail, you try to find a solution online, if you fail, you try to find a similar question here, and if you fail again, you post a question here, and you include all the things you tried, so peopple get much better idea about what you're trying to achieve. If your question looks like `write me teh coda, mo'fukerrz`, you're gonna get downvotes, bad answers, etc...

Comment: @vascowhite

i am sorry for doing such a reason
maybe it was easy for you
but for me it was like hell

but i did something for it

Comment: @enrey  i am sorry for doing such a reason maybe it was easy for you but for me it was like hell but i did something for it.

i just using code programming like 2 weeks ago..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $fulname="Dave Edward James David";
 $names = explode(" ", $fullname);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($names);
```

then you will have array $names like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dave
    [1] => Edward
    [2] => James
    [3] => David
)
```

then you can access  any element of result array by its index

```
echo $names[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

this is most likely using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, eg

```
$names = explode(" ", $fullname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're looking for a **basic** example, explode would do the trick.

```
$name = "Dave Edward James David";
$name_parts = explode(" ", $name);
// first name
echo $name_parts[0];
// first middle
echo $name_parts[1];
// sencond middle
echo $name_parts[2];
// last name
echo $name_parts[3];
```

But you can run into a would of issues if they have two names for a first name, or two last names, or three middle names. Though to tell. Best way would be individual text boxes for each name (first, middle, last).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the explode PHP function will do what you want.

```
$names = "Dave Edward James David";
$pieces = explode(" ", $names);
echo $pieces[0]; //Dave
echo $pieces[1]; //Edward
echo $pieces[2]; //James
echo $pieces[3]; //David
```

Answer (score 0):

you just try the name

```
    $name = array('dave','edwards','james','david');
    $string = imploid("%",$name);
```

get where you want to get it.and exploid it

```
     print_r(explode('%',$string));
```